# Javascript: always show Chrome address bar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, address-bar

How to enable **"always show"** address bar in Chrome on a mobile device using Javascript?
In other words, don't hide when the user **scrolls down**.

Comment: You could fake scrolling, but it's tricky.

Comment: You can wrap your HTML with div set its height 100%

Comment: @thesaurabhway how would that work? As I see it, you still get a scrolling page and a hiding address bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `div`, set the height to `100%` and use `overflow-y:auto;`.

If you would copy this code and paste it into your project, you will see this is what you're looking for.

Please use this with caution, I personally love that chrome hides the navigation bar.

Example:

```css
/* You NEED to set the container height */
html, body {
  height:100%;
}

/* Then override the scrollbar by a custom scrollable element: */
.customnavigation {
  height:100%;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="customnavigation">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
</div>
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't. Can you explain the theory?

Comment: @Alexander I've used a method like this for my page before, but you might need to adjust it slightly by giving it a `margin-top` and less height (`calc(100% - margin-top)`). The theorie is that this creates a box that has scrollable content, but the box itself is only as high as the page itself. Therefore, the `body` doesn't scroll, and doesn't trigger the header to be collapsed.

Comment: @Alexander You might find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298443/force-address-bar-to-show-in-mobile-chrome-app

Comment: That actually does the trick. What's in your opininon best for getting the height of the page minus the address bar, window.height?