# How to make address bar always visible on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

How to make address bar always visible on mobile browsers?

I try many of solutions like getting the body height and added it as CSS at HTML and body like this:

```
$("html, body").css({
   height: $(window).height()
});
```

And I try also something likes this:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 1);
```

But nothing change.

Comment: _“How to make address bar always visible on mobile browsers?”_ - not at all …? How, where and when the address bar is displayed is something I configure in my mobile browser. Why should you be able to mess with that?

Comment: Comedown ok? When you scroll down the address bar hidden by default this causes some issues with me.

Comment: Then you need to fix what _makes_ this an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other solutions on stackoverflow (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31412746/1106901) one) talk about preventing the `body` from scrolling. You are setting the body height, which is good, but the body still has a scrollbar. Try:

- Setting the `body` `overflow` to hidden.
- Adding a new `div` that is `height: 100%`; and `overflow: auto`. Put the entire page inside this div. The div will have the scrollbar instead of the body. (Read the linked solution carefully).

**Now, reasons I would discourage this**:

1. Users will hate you if you break the workflow they are used to. It is almost *never* the right thing to do.
2. Scrolling the body is always *much* faster than a div scrolling. You will see very noticeable performance decreases if the page is very big at all.

**Update: Address bar being moved**

Chrome on Android is experimenting with moving the address bar down to the bottom of the screen to be more accessible for single-hand use. This is a great example of why a web page should *never* try to add hacks to work around browser behavior.