# Prevent autohiding address bar

Tags: css, mobile, browser

I want to prevent autohiding the address bar in mobile browsers while scrolling. - I always want the address bar to be visible no matter how far I scrolled - Is there a clean way without javascript and the use of position fixed containers to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is (at the moment) no clean way to do it, as this is a browser setting which can't be ruled programmatically from within your website.

Because of that, your mentioned way with position:fixed way is of course a hack, which forces the viewport to stay extended.

The [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298443/force-address-bar-to-show-in-mobile-chrome-app#answer-25298650) even states, browsers explicitly prevent any manipulation of the adressbar, for security reasons.