# How can I prevent address bar from hiding in mobile browsers?

Tags: html, css, mobile

(learning html/css)

I designed a very simple [webpage](https://loiz.xyz/) (with some help) that has a fixed responsive margin around the viewport (screen). The problem is that in mobile browsers, the address bar pushes the page down, so the bottom margin is hidden. I want to prevent the address from hiding, and hopefully, I create a fully fixed image. I was already able to lock zooming with this on the

github repo: [enter link description here](https://github.com/Euclois/loiz.xyz)

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

I believe that locking the address bar is possible because [Fvckrenderverse](https://www.fvckrenderverse.com/#) has it locked on mobile, I want to do the same.

I tried adding this  to the  but the problem now is that it crops the margins top/bottom, but the address bar is locked at least. How do I lock it without cropping margins?

```
  <style type="text/css">
  html, body {margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden}
</style>
```

I've tried this script as well but nothing changed, address still hides on mobile.
I've tried other.

```
  <script>
function scrollWin() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
</script>
```

See, on the top/bottom, the margin has been cropped, where it is supposed to had a 20px white margin, like the sides. Here, the address bar is locked as I wish.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Address-Bar hiding in mobile Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061308/prevent-address-bar-hiding-in-mobile-browsers)

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't answer the problem. I've tried those solutions. I can't have the margins cropped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the answer, asked it on reddit. You can check the [solution here](https://www.reddit.com/r/csshelp/comments/sjkme6/comment/hvhat1g/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)
Basically, you add this to the  tag like I had, to lock the address bar:

```
 <script> function scrollWin() {  window.scrollTo(0, 0);} </script>
```

Then in the  tag you change:

from:

```
width: calc(100vw - 40px);
height: calc(100vh - 40px);
```

...to...

```
width: calc(100% - 40px);
height: calc(100% - 40px);
```

(change from vw/vh to %)

Simple answer!